# After 15 minutes of inactivity, session should be expired within the application in symfony framework

Tags: php, symfony

After 15 minutes of inactivity, session should be expired within the application in symfony .

I have tried so far:
set in config.yml file

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 900
```

It logout from the application in 15 min. even user active.
But I want to show if the user inactive within 15 min. then it should logout. Otherwise it should not.

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1):

Becareful, some next-level-trick there, I'm not an expert on this one

If you have a custom User entity which represents a user, you can possibly add a new member to it named "last_activity" and check if he's still active when you reach the controller method :

```
$user->last_activity + 900 >= time()
```

If it's true, log the user out. Else, just modify last_activity this way :

```
$user->last_activity = time();
```

There may be better solution (Symfony native) but I don't know it so feel free to complete :)

Comment: But I didnt getting what is 'last_activity'? Is it new field from user table which stores activity of user?

Comment: Well, i'm sorry if my explanation wasn't that good. If Symfony does not provide tools to track "real activity" for your sessions, then you would have to do it yourself. The "last_activity" I mentioned was, in my mind, a timestamp that would be stored into the User session class. If you don't need other people to see who is active, then you do not need to store it in database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to do it is as below:

```
session:    
    cookie_lifetime: 7200
    gc_maxlifetime: 900
```

You can read further here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html